# Kendo scheduler resources paging

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, paging, kendo-scheduler, angular-kendo

in kendo scheduler control am using group header template and would like to make a paging in my resources view

http://dojo.telerik.com/IMUjA

this example has 2 only resources if I would like to add 2 another resources I want to show only 2 resources per page and would like to have next/prev buttons to change resources viewed as paging in scheduler displaying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want something such as the example I made in this link:

[dojo.telerik.com/uBigO/4](http://dojo.telerik.com/@mustafa_elhelbawy/uBigO/4)

I would like to control my resources to view configured number of the resources cause the pagination method is not supported in Kendo scheduler as a feature hope it will be a feature as soon as possible in stead of implementing it manually.

Hope this to be helpful for everyone

Comment: any refactoring for my code are very welcomed and please provide a link with the refactored code if you did to keep on touch and share our ideas,  thanks in advance