# How to use only the scheduler of kendo ui by importing ONLY kendo.scheduler.min

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, requirejs, kendo-scheduler, telerik-scheduler

I am trying to create a custom scheduler using kendo ui scheduler but I am having some performance issues (render time of over 10s). To resolve this, I tried only to import (using **requirejs**) the **kendo.scheduler.min** file but I am getting tons of errors like this one, but just with different files.

```
Uncaught Error: Script error for "kendo.dropdownlist.min", needed by: kendo.scheduler.min
```

My question is, do I really need to import all the files shown in the error to get kendo working? Is there other way to use kendo.scheduler.min without having to import all those other scripts?

Comment: What is the Kendo UI version? Can you show the requireJS configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For kendo-UI schduler only "kendo.scheduler.min" is not enough because to change the date you have to add "kendo.datepicker.js" and to open insert/Update window you have to add "kendo.window.js" into the page.

Please check [this link](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/supporting/scripts-scheduling) to know the script files list for the Kendo UI Scheduling widgets.

Let me know if any concern.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late to answer I too was facing the same issue.

1. You can use only the necessary package from **[here](https://www.telerik.com/download/custom-download)**
2. Other way you could actually reduce the **render time** is by reducing the 
   amount of data coming at a time.
   I have implemented this by doing a **resource paging** in my scheduler. It 
   has reduced the render drastically.

[kendo-scheduler-resources-paging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38934150/6481897)

you can follow this link.
Hope this helps anyone with the same issue :)