# Kendo Scheduler load time and responsiveness decrease with high volume of data

Tags: angularjs, ajax, performance, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

In our application we have data for more than 200 rooms . We fetch data for all the rooms from the back end in one api call within a particular date range (10 or 15 days range) which can have large amount of data. If we bind all the data to the scheduler the rendering is very slow.

So instead of binding all data at once, Is there a way we could bind the data to the scheduler on scroll like that of in endless scroll for ajax requests?

I did found endless scroll for Kendo grid which is provided out of the box but is not available for scheduler.

Comment: You can create a JSON and update that JSON in given interval and include that JSON file where you want

Comment: Or you can use lazy loading.

Comment: sorry for the delay @GauravKandpal for the reply. The scheduler data is loaded according to resource value provided so in order to achieve we must identify which resource the data belongs to and so on many other problems.
When contacted telerik team they confirmed virtualization or lazy loading is not possible in the widget....as of yet that is
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those who are looking to make kendo scheduler much faster I would recommend you to follow this method

[kendo-scheduler-resources-paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643828/kendo-scheduler-resources-paging)

Comment: It's better to include short summary and the main points of the solution, in case the page you're linking to becomes unavailable.