# Kendo Gantt charts vs kendo scheduler

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui

As the heading says which is better for implementing application mainly for making reservations [kendo gantt chart](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/gantt/index) or [kendo scheduler](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/angular)

Currently I'm using kendo scheduler and there is an issue when it comes to rendering a large amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo Gantt charts and kendo scheduler both have almost same properties . The difference is the purpose of tools .

**Kendo Gantt charts :**

The Kendo UI Gantt widget displays a set of tasks and dependencies, which are used to visualize project planning data. The widget provides a TreeList section where the tasks can be edited, sorted and reordered in a grid-like fashion, as well as a Timeline section, where the tasks and dependencies are visualized under an adjustable time ruler, and can be resized, moved, edited and removed. It can also display the Timeline in three different views – day, week and month.

**Kendo Scheduler  :**

The Telerik Kendo UI Scheduler allows you to easily schedule, display and edit appointments. You can display day, week, month, timeline and agenda views, group horizontally and vertically and enjoy out-of-the-box templates.

**Both have almost same capacity to handle and manage data.**

**If you are facing issue using scheduler with huge amount of data then you can use retrieve and Communicate with DB manually using this following events**

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/events

Comment: thank you for the response but i solved the slowness issue from here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643828/kendo-scheduler-resources-paging